# Spring-boot. A bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I can't seem to figure out why my spring boot application isn't able to automatically create a SessionFactory. As I understand it's supposed to automatically pick up the properties file and be able to create the session factory bean.

I'd need to use the session factory inside of some Dao classes together with hibernate, however the simple example below reproduces the issue that I'm having:

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>mytools</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-hello-world</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <start-class>mytools.spring.hello.Application</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:databaseFiles/hibData/;hsqldb.write_delay_millis=0
spring.datasource.root=sa
spring.datasource.password=1

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true
```

Application class:

```
package mytools.spring.hello;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
    "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin\java" -Dvisualvm.id=13106393222439 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=51221:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath D:\Projects\Java\springboothelloworld\target\classes;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.0.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.0.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.0.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.0.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.0.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.10.0\log4j-to-slf4j-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.10.0\log4j-api-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.25\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.0.5.RELEASE\spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.0.5.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.19\snakeyaml-1.19.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.0.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-json-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.5\jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.5\jackson-core-2.9.5.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.9.5\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.5.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.5\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.5.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.5\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.5.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.0.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\8.5.29\tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\8.5.29\tomcat-embed-el-8.5.29.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\8.5.29\tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.29.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.9.Final\hibernate-validator-6.0.9.Final.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.3.4\classmate-1.3.4.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.0.5.RELEASE\spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.0.5.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.0.5.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.0.5.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.0.5.RELEASE\spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.0.5.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.0.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.0.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.13\aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.0.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\2.7.8\HikariCP-2.7.8.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.0.5.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.2.16.Final\hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api\1.0.0.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.22.0-GA\javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.0.3.Final\jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.0.1.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\javax\transaction\javax.transaction-api\1.2\javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.0.6.RELEASE\spring-data-jpa-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.0.6.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.0.5.RELEASE\spring-orm-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.0.5.RELEASE\spring-tx-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.0.5.RELEASE\spring-aspects-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\org\hsqldb\hsqldb\2.3.4\hsqldb-2.3.4.jar;C:\Users\owner\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.3.0\jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar mytools.spring.hello.Application

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.1.RELEASE)

2018-05-12 00:46:57.170  INFO 7944 --- [           main] mytools.spring.hello.Application         : Starting Application on Hulk with PID 7944 (D:\Projects\Java\springboothelloworld\target\classes started by owner in D:\Projects\Java\springboothelloworld)
2018-05-12 00:46:57.170  INFO 7944 --- [           main] mytools.spring.hello.Application         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-05-12 00:46:57.220  INFO 7944 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@5340477f: startup date [Sat May 12 00:46:57 EEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/C:/Users/owner/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.0.5.RELEASE/spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2018-05-12 00:46:58.078  INFO 7944 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6f5d8399] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-05-12 00:46:58.370  INFO 7944 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-05-12 00:46:58.390  INFO 7944 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-05-12 00:46:58.390  INFO 7944 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.29
2018-05-12 00:46:58.395  INFO 7944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\libnvvp;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\libnvvp;C:\Intel\OpenCL\sdk\bin\x64;C:\Intel\OpenCL\sdk\bin\x86;C:\Intel\OpenCL\sdk\bin\Pin;C:\Intel\OpenCL\sdk\bin\GTPin;C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.2.1\lib\extralibs\bin;C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.2.1\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\libnvvp;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Anaconda3;C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.2.1\mingw\bin;D:\RunnableBins\myrepos;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\HaskellStack\bin;C:\Users\owner\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin;C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;.]
2018-05-12 00:46:58.480  INFO 7944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-05-12 00:46:58.480  INFO 7944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1260 ms
2018-05-12 00:46:58.570  INFO 7944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-05-12 00:46:58.575  INFO 7944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-12 00:46:58.575  INFO 7944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-12 00:46:58.575  INFO 7944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-12 00:46:58.575  INFO 7944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-12 00:46:58.695  INFO 7944 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-05-12 00:46:58.875  INFO 7944 --- [           main] hsqldb.db..ENGINE                        : open start - state modified
2018-05-12 00:46:58.885  INFO 7944 --- [           main] hsqldb.db..ENGINE                        : checkpointClose start
2018-05-12 00:46:58.885  INFO 7944 --- [           main] hsqldb.db..ENGINE                        : checkpointClose synched
2018-05-12 00:46:58.895  INFO 7944 --- [           main] hsqldb.db..ENGINE                        : checkpointClose script done
2018-05-12 00:46:58.915  INFO 7944 --- [           main] hsqldb.db..ENGINE                        : checkpointClose end
2018-05-12 00:46:58.915  INFO 7944 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (feature not supported)
2018-05-12 00:46:58.915  INFO 7944 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-05-12 00:46:58.945  INFO 7944 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-05-12 00:46:58.960  INFO 7944 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-05-12 00:46:59.010  INFO 7944 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.16.Final}
2018-05-12 00:46:59.010  INFO 7944 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-05-12 00:46:59.040  INFO 7944 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-05-12 00:46:59.120  INFO 7944 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
2018-05-12 00:46:59.320  INFO 7944 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-05-12 00:46:59.335  WARN 7944 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2018-05-12 00:46:59.335  INFO 7944 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-05-12 00:46:59.335  INFO 7944 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-05-12 00:46:59.380  INFO 7944 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2018-05-12 00:46:59.385  INFO 7944 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-05-12 00:46:59.390  INFO 7944 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-05-12 00:46:59.450 ERROR 7944 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field sessionFactory in mytools.spring.hello.Application required a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My problem was that I was expecting Spring Boot JPA auto-configuration to automatically configure and wire up the SessionFactory for my Hibernate DAOs.

SessionFactory is specific to Hibernate, and Spring Boot Autowires the EntityManager object instead, which is more generic to JPA.

Swapping SessionFactory to EntityManager in my Dao objects allowed me to use Spring's auto-configuration to wire everything up.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you autowired `SessionFactory` without define `Bean`. The solutions may have below
1. Remove `@Autowired SessionFactory sessionFactory`

2. Put this code

   `@Bean public SessionFactory getSessionFactory {return new SessionFactory()}`

   after this bean initialisation you can autowired `SessionFactory`

Answer (score 2):

May be this is late.
I had same problem with my Spring boot project, In my case spring boot configuration for database not configured automatically.
Hence, I created `@Bean` for my `SessionFactory` in my configuration file separately. After which I was able to `@Autowired` my `SessionFactory`.
Here is the method which I followed:

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
       LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
       sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
      return sessionFactory;
    }

@Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().driverClassName(/*Your driver driverClassName*/)
                .username(/*Your DB username*/).password(/*Your DB Password*/)
                .url(/*Your DB URL*/).build();
    }
```

Hope This will help.